# Не могу добавить функцию в телеграм боте

Tags: python, telebot

Не могу добавить функцию

```
import random
def random_text():
  array = [
  'Текст',
  'Текст',
  'Текст',
  'Тексt'
  ]

  print( "Текст: " + random.choice(array) )

  if random.choice(array) == 'Текст':
    print("It's working")
  else:
    print("Текст")
random_text()
```

В телеграм бота

```
import telebot
import random

bot = telebot.TeleBot("Token Bota")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if message.text == 'Random':#Если пользователь напишет рандом,то
     #здесь должна запуститься функция     
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Я тебя не понимаю')
```

Никак просто не получается

Comment: Что не получается? Какая ошибка?

Comment: Просто в боте эта функция не работает

Comment: Я как-то так пытался добавить:

Comment: import telebot
import random

bot = telebot.TeleBot("Token Bota")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if message.text == 'Random':
      random_fact()
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Я тебя не понимаю')

# Вот функция
import random

def random_fact():
  array = [
  'Текст',
  'Текст',
  'Текст',
  'Тексt'
  ]

  print( "Текст: " + random.choice(array) )

  if random.choice(array) == 'Текст':
    print("It's working")
  else:
    print("Текст")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно, чтобы бот показывал результат функции пользователю, а не просто делал принт, то вот так нужно поменять саму функцию:

```
def random_text():
    array = [
        'Текст',
        'Текст',
        'Текст',
        'Тексt'
    ]

    if random.choice(array) == 'Текст':
        return "It's working"
    else:
        return "Текст"
```

а вот так подключить её в бота:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if message.text == 'Random':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, random_text())    
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Я тебя не понимаю')
```